# Getting twitter feed into NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, nsarray

How would I get the text of the last 10 tweets, for a specific twitter user, into an NSArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to parse the json with something similar to what is described here: http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c and here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/

Answer (score 2):

In more modern versions of iOS, you can access Twitter directly via the [Social Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html). [Twitter has some example code available](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-slrequest) which shows how to use it.

You could, if you need something for earlier versions of iOS, check out [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/). It'll take care of all the heavy lifting required. Specifically, the methods  `getUserTimelineFor sinceID startingAtPage count` and `getUserTimelineFor sinceID withMaximumID startingAtPage count` will fetch what you're looking for. It is getting a little long in the tooth, however, so making use of the built-in iOS stuff is preferable.

Comment: probably a bit heavy for my needs

Comment: Possibly. Remember though, with Twitter, it's simple until it isn't.